# The system cannot find the file specified in Kotlin

Tags: java, file, kotlin

I try to read from file in same package so when i run code it give me error

```
var buffer: BufferedReader? = null

val result = try {

    buffer = BufferedReader(FileReader("file.txt"))
    val chars = CharArray(30)
    buffer.read(chars, 0, 40)
    0
} catch (e: IndexOutOfBoundsException) {
    println(" Exception handle")
    1
} catch(e: FileNotFoundException) {
    println(e.message)
    2
} finally {
    buffer?.close()
    println("closed")
}

println(result)
```

**output :**

file.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)

closed

2

when i specify full path `FileNoFoundException` not throw why ?.

```
var buffer: BufferedReader? = null

val result = try {
    buffer = BufferedReader(FileReader("C:\\Users\\Mahmood Ali\\IdeaProjects\\Kotlin wih hadi\\src\\tidbits\\file.txt"))
    val chars = CharArray(30)
    buffer.read(chars, 0, 40)
    0
} catch (e: IndexOutOfBoundsException) {
    println("Exception handle")
    1
} catch(e: FileNotFoundException) {
    println(e.message)
    2
} finally {
    buffer?.close()
    println("closed")
}

println(result)
```

**output:**

Exception handle

closed

1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass a filename without a path, the JVM is going to look for that file in the **current working directory**, not the package folder of the class you're making the call from. So, to use relative paths, you have to first find out the working directory of your program, which should usually be the root folder of the project if you're running it from intelliJ.