# Why is reading from a file in Kotlin using ForEachLine not working?

Tags: kotlin

I am developing a bank app where I can store customer's details and load them. So to load the customer's details from a file, I created a function called " read from a file". In the function, I used the File.ForEachLine, which reads each line. However, I am getting an error when I try to add the filename from which to read.

**This is my code:**

```
fun readFromFile() {
    println("What is the file name?")
    var filename = readLine().toString()
       File(filename).forEachLine {
           os -> os.split(",")
           val name = os[0]?.toString()
           val address = os[1]?.toString()
           val phone = os[2]?.toLong()
           var customer = Customer(name, address, phone)
           list_of_customers.add(customer)
    }
}
```

**The error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: customers.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:211)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:153)
    at kotlin.io.FilesKt__FileReadWriteKt.forEachLine(FileReadWrite.kt:190)
    at kotlin.io.FilesKt__FileReadWriteKt.forEachLine$default(FileReadWrite.kt:188)
    at Bank_AppKt.readFromFile(Bank App.kt:142)
    at Bank_AppKt.displayMenu(Bank App.kt:16)
    at Bank_AppKt.main(Bank App.kt:9)
    at Bank_AppKt.main(Bank App.kt)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The system cannot find the file specified in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44969903/the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-in-kotlin)

Comment: You should print out the current working directory and the filename, to be sure you know where your code is expecting the file to be.  I'm confident that you'll find that where your code is looking isn't where the file is.  That's the only reason for this error.  @flaxel's suggestion gives more info on this.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a file `customers.txt` with the following contents in the `src` folder of your project:

```
Adam,1 Apple Lane,1111111111
Bill,2 Banana Road,2222222222
```

Visualization of project structure (using IntelliJ IDEA as IDE):

```
~/IdeaProjects/KotlinStackoverflow 
├── KotlinStackoverflow.iml
├── out
│   └── production
│       └── KotlinStackoverflow
│           ├── Customer.class
│           ├── META-INF
│           │   └── KotlinStackoverflow.kotlin_module
│           ├── MainKt$readFromFile$1.class
│           ├── MainKt.class
│           └── customers.txt
└── src
    ├── Main.kt
    └── customers.txt
```

The following should work to create a list of `Customer` objects from the lines in the file:

```
import java.io.File

data class Customer(val name: String, val address: String, val phone: Long)

fun readFromFile(): MutableList<Customer> {
    print("What is the file name? ")
    val fileName = readLine().toString()
    val listOfCustomers = mutableListOf<Customer>()
    try {
        File(fileName).forEachLine {
            val os = it.split(",")
            val name = os[0].toString()
            val address = os[1].toString()
            val phone = os[2].toLong()
            listOfCustomers.add(Customer(name, address, phone))
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return customers
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val listOfCustomers = readFromFile()
    for (customer in listOfCustomers) {
        println(customer)
    }
}
```

***N.B.*** *I need to provide the full file path from the content root of the project when I enter in the file name, you may need to do this or enter in the absolute file path to get it to work.*

**Example Usage 1:**

```
What is the file name? customers.txt
java.io.FileNotFoundException: customers.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at kotlin.io.FilesKt__FileReadWriteKt.forEachLine(FileReadWrite.kt:190)
    at kotlin.io.FilesKt__FileReadWriteKt.forEachLine$default(FileReadWrite.kt:188)
    at MainKt.readFromFile(Main.kt:10)
    at MainKt.main(Main.kt:24)
```

**Example Usage 2:**

```
What is the file name? src/customers.txt
Customer(name=Adam, address=1 Apple Lane, phone=1111111111)
Customer(name=Bill, address=2 Banana Road, phone=2222222222)
```

**Example Usage 3:**

```
What is the file name? /Users/shash/IdeaProjects/KotlinStackoverflow/src/customers.txt
Customer(name=Adam, address=1 Apple Lane, phone=1111111111)
Customer(name=Bill, address=2 Banana Road, phone=2222222222)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question though.  The question is why the OP is getting a `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: Aren't they likely just typing the filename and not the full file path from the content root?

Comment: Who knows.  The OP doesn't say.  My guess is that they're typing just the filename, or the filename with a relative path, and are making an incorrect assumption about the current working directory (about where the relative path they're providing is based).

Comment: @ShashSinha, it is still giving me the same error even if I try putting full file path

Comment: WierdChamp Are you using IntelliJ idea?

Comment: Not sure tbh, unfortunately. I would try to create a new barebones project with a similar structure as above and see if it works.